# Name of an indicator based on price change and volume

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, indicator

If a(t) is the price of an asset and v(t) is the transaction volume of that asset against say USD, one can look at the integral over a time period of v(t) a'(t).

In words, this is the cumulative volume-weighted price variation. Does this quantity have a name?